# How to repeat 'onclick' function with AJAX within ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run new AJAX upload and insert a data element from the `onClick` of an item to multirow , the problem is it work for first row and when I add another row the function is not working when I click on it .

HTML code is :

```
   <table id="images" class="list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_image; ?></td>
            <td class="right"><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $image_row = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($product_images as $product_image) { ?>
        <tbody id="image-row<?php echo $image_row; ?>">
          <tr>
            <td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $product_image['thumb']; ?>" alt="" id="thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][image]" value="<?php echo $product_image['image']; ?>" id="image<?php echo $image_row; ?>" />
                <br />
                <a onclick="image_upload('image<?php echo $image_row; ?>', 'thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>');" id="imagerow<?php echo $image_row; ?>" class="rowman"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$('#thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>').attr('src', '<?php echo $no_image; ?>'); $('#image<?php echo $image_row; ?>').attr('value', '');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>
            <td class="right"><input type="text" name="product_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][sort_order]" value="<?php echo $product_image['sort_order']; ?>" size="2" /></td>
            <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#image-row<?php echo $image_row; ?>').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php $image_row++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="left"><a onclick="addImage();" class="button"><?php echo $button_add_image; ?></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

javascript code for Add function for row is :

```js
var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;

function addImage() {


    html  = '<tbody id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
 html += '  <tr>';
 html += '    <td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $no_image; ?>" alt="" id="thumb' + image_row + '" /><input type="hidden" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="image' + image_row + '" /><br /><a onclick="image_upload(\'image' + image_row + '\', \'thumb' + image_row + '\');" id="imagerow' + image_row + '" class="rowman"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$(\'#thumb' + image_row + '\').attr(\'src\', \'<?php echo $no_image; ?>\'); $(\'#image' + image_row + '\').attr(\'value\', \'\');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>';
 html += '    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][sort_order]" value="" size="2" /></td>';
 html += '    <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#image-row' + image_row  + '\').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>';
 html += '  </tr>';
 html += '</tbody>';
 
 $('#images tfoot').before(html);
 
 image_row++;
}
```

and jQuery code for `onclick` function is :

```js
function image_upload(field, thumb) {
var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;
 new AjaxUpload('#imagerow'+image_row ,{
 action: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/upload&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
  name: 'image',
  autoSubmit: true,
  responseType: 'json',
      
  onChange: function(file, extension) {
   
   this.setData({'directory': ''});
         this.submit();
  },
      
  onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
   $('#upload').append('<img src="catalog/view/theme/mall/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
  },
  onComplete: function(file, json) {
   if (json.success) {
              $('#' + field).attr('value','data/user/'+file)
    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(text) {
      $('#' + thumb).replaceWith('<img src="' + text + '" alt="" id="' + thumb + '" />');            
     }
    });
   }
   
   if (json.error) {
    alert(json.error);
   }
            
   $('.loading').remove(); 
  }
 });
 
 
};
```

here is a pic for explanation 
[image: description image]

can I get help?

Comment: i want help for this problem and pls rewrite jquery code for that with your solution

Answer (score 1):

You should probably divide your javascript from your DOM.
If you use JQuery you could do something like this:

`<td class="left"><a data-image-row="<?php echo $image_row; ?>" class="button image-row-remove"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>`

and then use `on`, so JQuery can also recognize new elements:

```
$(body).on('click', '.image-row-remove', function(){ 
  $('#image-row' + this.data('image-row')).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the click function to every dynamic generated element. Try this to append your function to every (also dynamically generated) elements in DOM.

```
$('body').on('click', '.yourlink', function(e) {

}
```

And change your code (you dont need a onclick function, just give them a certain class and (if needed) a unique id)

Comment: can you rewrite my last jquery code as you explain to can try it

Answer (score 0):

finally i found solution with help from my friend @EraMax

at part of HTML code  at button :

```
<a  onclick="image_upload('image<?php echo $image_row; ?>', 'thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>');" id="imagerow<?php echo $image_row; ?>"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>
```

we will add id to onclick event as following

```
<a  onclick="image_upload('image<?php echo $image_row; ?>', 'thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>' ,'imagerow<?php echo $image_row; ?>');" id="imagerow<?php echo $image_row; ?>" class="upimage"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>
```

on code of generated row at point of onclick button change :

```
    html += '    <td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $no_image; ?>" alt="" id="thumb' + image_row + '" /><input type="hidden" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="image' + image_row + '" /><br /><a onclick="image_upload(\'image' + image_row + '\', \'thumb' + image_row + '\');" id="imagerow' + image_row + '" class="rowman"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$(\'#thumb' + image_row + '\').attr(\'src\', \'<?php echo $no_image; ?>\'); $(\'#image' + image_row + '\').attr(\'value\', \'\');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>';
```

to

```
    html += '<td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $no_image; ?>" alt="" id="thumb' + image_row + '" /><input type="hidden" name="shop_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="image' + image_row + '" /><br /><a onclick="image_upload(\'image' + image_row + '\', \'thumb' + image_row + '\' , \'imagerow' + image_row + '\');" id="imagerow' + image_row + '" ><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$(\'#thumb' + image_row + '\').attr(\'src\', \'<?php echo $no_image; ?>\'); $(\'#image' + image_row + '\').attr(\'value\', \'\');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>';
```

finally in jQuery code  for onclick event

```
function  image_upload(image, thumb, image_row ){
new AjaxUpload('#'+image_row  , {
action: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/upload&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
name: 'image',
autoSubmit: true,
responseType: 'json',

onChange: function(file, extension) {

    this.setData({'directory': ''});
 this.submit();
},

onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
    $('#'+image_row).append('<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
},
onComplete: function(file, json) {
    if (json.success) {
     $('#' + field).attr('value','data/user/'+file);
        $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(text) {
            $('#' + thumb).replaceWith('<img src="' + text + '" alt="" id="' + thumb + '" />');                          
            }
        });
    }

    if (json.error) {
        alert(json.error);
    }

    $('.loading').remove(); 
}
 });

    };
```

I hope this is help everyone seek this solution